# Spawn invisible Bat - convert org.bukkit.Entity to org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.entity.CraftBat;

Tags: java, bukkit

I'm creating a Plugin that need some invisible Bats. I therefore have a method that spawns and stores my bats. This is the code, I currently have:

```java
public class BatManager {
    private static final List<Entity> bats = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void spawnBat(Location location) {
        Entity entity = location.getWorld().spawnEntity(location, EntityType.BAT);
        try {
            CraftBat l = (CraftBat) entity;
            l.getHandle().setInvisible(true);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        bats.add(entity);
    }
}
```

This code does compile, however it does not make the bat invisible. I strongly suspect that I create a copy of the object at some point, and set the invisibility there. I'm not sure however how I can set the invisibility without the conversion to CraftBat, since there are no methods I know of, to make a `org.bukkit.Entity` invisible on its' own.

How can I correct this?

I'm open for other suggestions concerning the invisibility as well, but I do explicitly not want to use Potion effects, since those leave some particles for the Player to see.

Comment: You can add potion effect ? Also, I know that armor stand have `setVisible(false)` but not bat on spigot 1.8

Comment: I specifically do not want to use potion effects, see my explaination above. Also, I'm not using armor stands, I'm using bats, which do not have this possibility. `setVisible` is specific for armor stands.

Comment: From spigot's thread, wait 2 ticks before set invisible works (sorry i don't have the time to test it)

Comment: I have read the available posts on the issue, and if you can explain me how to get the proper instance of `CraftBat` I'll be delighted to do as you suggested ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution without packet. With a quick timer, it's fine :

```java
Entity bat = location.getWorld().spawnEntity(location, EntityType.BAT);
Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater(MyPlugin.getInstance(), () -> {
    ((CraftBat) bat).getHandle().setInvisible(true);
}, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found an alternate solution. It's actually possible to hide the particles per default on bukkit side. I therefore used PotionEffect's, looking like this:

```java
Entity entity = location.getWorld().spawnEntity(location, EntityType.BAT); 
LivingEntity livingEntity = (LivingEntity) entity;
PotionEffect effect = new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.INVISIBILITY, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 1, false, false);
livingEntity.addPotionEffect(effect);
bats.add(livingEntity);
```